# Инициализация ArrayList заданными элементами

Tags: java

есть большой массив типа `String s[ ]={"a", "b", "c", "d"};`
но мне нужно сделать в `ArrayList< String > as`, чтобы можно было удалять элементы. Метод копирования из `String s[ ]` в `ArrayList` не подходит, нужно сразу внести, а вводить методом `as.add("a")` и т.д. очень неудобно. Как ввести все элементы одной строкой? т.е. можно ли как в `String s[ ]={"a", "b", "c", "d"};`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Можно. Вам нужен метод `Arrays.asList(...)`, который является популярным способом создать список из заранее известных элементов.

```
List<String> as = Arrays.asList("a", "b", "c", "d");
```

Но есть одно **но**. Полученный список не будет настоящим `ArrayList`-ом. В целом это не будет вас задевать, если вы не захотите, например, сериализовать этот список.

"Честный" `ArrayList` можно получить, обернув список в конструктор:

```
 List<String> as = new ArrayList(Arrays.asList("a", "b", "c", "d"));
```

Comment: огромное спасибо, попробую!